# Need some help with the usage of 'as' here

Tags: as

> Did you ever stop to think that God is going to be **as** pleased to have you with Him in Heaven as you are to be there?

1. Is 'did' at the head of the sentence used as a polite usage of past tense? Like, is it the case that they didn't actually ask someone had done something in the past, rather just being polite?
2. I can't understand why they used 'as' between 'be' and 'pleased'. Is it something like "I'm as tall as my father"? If so, it would get even harder for me to interpret the meaning of it. Then, would it be like, "God is going to be pleased to have you the same degree as you'd be when you get there"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, "Did you ever X" is actually asking whether the person has done X in the past.  Depending on context and tone, "did you ever" constructions may be sarcastic ("did you ever think how that would make ME feel!?" implies "you never thought about how that would make me feel, or if you thought about it, you obviously didn't care").  I suppose they could equally be polite rhetorical questions when it is assumed the answer is true, but there is nothing inherent to the construction either way.  In itself it is just a question.
2. Yes, you are right.  It is "God is going to be equally pleased to have you with him as you are going to be pleased to be there".